# Unable to create IBM postgress service on IBM satellite location

Tags: ibm-cloud, satellite

We have created IBM satellite location on AWS which is successful.
Now trying to setup IBM postgress service on the same location using the IBM CLI. However getting error

Taking help of blog:  https://medium.com/hybrid-cloud-engineering/using-ibm-cloud-satellite-to-run-example-banking-app-on-openshift-and-ibm-cloud-databases-in-aws-ddc96eae8ec4

Use case: Create AWS  location with 3 control plane nodes and 3 worker nodes where postgres will be installed. We dont plan to install OpenShift.

1. Create storage config

```
#ibmcloud sat storage config create  --name 'aws-ebs-config-storage-testing-1'  --template-name 'aws-ebs-csi-driver'  --template-version '1.12.0'  --location 'XXXXXXXXXXX'  -p "aws-access-key=XXXXXXX"  -p "aws-secret-access-key=XXXXXXXXXX"
Creating Satellite storage configuration...
OK
Storage configuration 'aws-ebs-config-storage-testing-1' was successfully created with ID 'aeb91c49-2f7e-468b-8b3a-37947f503de5'.
```

2. 

```
#ibmcloud sat location dns register --location 'cgmeurhw094m5mkaav9g' --ip 3.83.21.39 --ip 54.145.158.164 --ip 52.201.235.118
Registering a subdomain for control plane hosts...
FAILED
You do not have the correct permissions to perform this action, or the context based rules prevent the action from being completed in your current location. Ask your account administrator to give you the Editor platform role for the cluster in IBM Cloud Identity and Access Management (IAM) and to ensure that your current IP address is permitted. Then, try again. (A0008)
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure you have correct number/type of hosts for ICD in addition to satellite control plane (https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-for-postgresql?topic=databases-for-postgresql-satellite-aws&interface=ui):

> Three type 8x32 hosts for IBM Cloud™ Databases (ICD) enabled by IBM Cloud
> Satellite internal use. Nodes are auto-assigned to a service
> cluster.
>
> - On AWS, choose three hosts of type AWS m5d.2xlarge
>
> Three type 32x128 hosts for your use.
>
> - On AWS choose three hosts of type AWS m5d.8xlarge

Second, you dont need to change satellite control plane to the public interfaces. In the article you mentioned it was only required to have public access to OpenShift console. Double check the latest documentation:

- [Setting up Amazon Web Services (AWS) for Satellite](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/satellite?topic=satellite-aws)
- [Setting up Amazon Web Services Location for PostgreSQL](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-for-postgresql?topic=databases-for-postgresql-satellite-aws&interface=ui)

Third, the error you are seeing says that you do not have correct permissions in the IBM CLoud IAM. In this case it complains about **Editor platform role**. Check satellite role requirements here - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/satellite?topic=satellite-iam-platform-access